# Making existing tables usable on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I'm working with legacy HTML, with a bunch of nested tables that are not used for tabular data. Is there any way I could make these tables more usable on 320px width screens? Currently, I have them overflow: auto for horizontal scrolling. It's not ideal. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/DUUWv/

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" style="awful">
```

I've tried several responsive table libraries; however, understandably, they're all geared toward tabular data and don't work for my purpose.

Comment: I feel like the time and effort required to make tables work for something they're not made for is more than the time and effort required to convert them to something more modern even when dealing with legacy code. If you're able to modify the actual html and not just css, take a look at [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/).

Comment: Yeah, I know how awful it is. My boss knows how awful it is. Unfortunately, we're stuck with the HTML as-is for the time being. I love both Bootstrap and Foundation, and usually incorporate one of them in my own projects. I figured there wouldn't be much I could do here. Thanks for your help, Jeff.